# How to get youtube video id from URL with java

Tags: java, regex

I try to get the `id` of a YouTube video URL. Here's an example of you such an url:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iz6aR-WATYY
```

How can I get just the ID of this video?

this is video_Adapter

```
public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Video> videoList;
private Context context;
String videourl;
Intent intent;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView image, videonextarrowImage;
    public TextView desc;
    public TextView videourl;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_imageView);
        desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_desc);
        videourl = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_url);
        videonextarrowImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_NextArrow);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Video_Activity.class);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}


public VideoAdapter(List<Video> videoList, Context context) {
    this.videoList = videoList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_list_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Video video = videoList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(video.getTitle());
    holder.videourl.setText(video.getVideourl());
    //holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.more_selector);
    holder.desc.setText(video.getDesc());
    holder.videonextarrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.nextbutton);
    context = holder.image.getContext();
    Picasso.with(context).load("http://bitstobyte.in/upload/" + video.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.play).error(R.drawable.startyoutubevideo).resize(50, 50).into(holder.image);

    holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String Title = video.getTitle();
            String Desc = video.getDesc();

            String[] links = new String[]{video.getVideourl()};
            String[] ids = new String[links.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                ids[i] = links[i].split("v=")[1];
            }

            intent = new Intent(context, Video_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Video_title", Title);
            intent.putExtra("Vide_desc", Desc);
            intent.putExtra("Video_ID", ids);
            context.startActivity(intent);

            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + video.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return videoList.size();
}
```

}

this is video.java

```
public class Video extends VideoResponse{

public String title;
public String image;
public String desc;
private String videourl;

public Video(){

}
public Video(String title, String image, String desc,String videourl) {
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
    this.videourl = videourl;
    this.desc = desc;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String name) {
    this.title = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
public String getVideourl() {
    return videourl;
}

public void setVideourl(String videourl) {
    this.videourl = videourl;
}
```

}

this is video_activity.java

```
public class Video_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

TextView textView1, textView2;
ScrollView scrollView;
WebView webView;
VideoView videoView;
private MediaController mController;
private Uri uriYouTube;
private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
Video video;
public String videourl;
// Google Console APIs developer key
// Replace this key with your's
public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyC0rjDLc0jkYY0Z66QgOnkNmkOAyOqpqnI";

// YouTube video id
//public static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE = "yExScIwJftE";
String[] ids;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#fdfafa'> Video View </font>"));

    final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment frag = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_view);
    if (frag == null) {
        frag = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.youtube_view, frag).commit();
    }

    frag.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (null != intent) {
        String Video_Title = intent.getStringExtra("Video_title");
        String Video_Desc = intent.getStringExtra("Vide_desc");
        ids = intent.getStringArrayExtra("Video_ID");
        //Log.i("Video_Url", " " + YouTube_VideoPlayer);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_video_Title);
        textView1.setText(Video_Title);

        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_video_desc);
        textView2.setText(Video_Desc);

        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Scroller_Id_video);
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, textView2.getBottom());
            }
        });
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure (YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason){

        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        }
        else
        {
            //String YouTube_VidePlayer = getIntent().getStringExtra("Video_Player");
            String YouTube_VideoPlayer = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, YouTube_VideoPlayer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess (YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,YouTubePlayer player,boolean wasRestored){

        if (!wasRestored) {
            // loadVideo() will auto play video
            // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically

            //player.cueVideo(YouTube_VideoPlayer);

            player.cueVideo(String.valueOf(ids));

            // Hiding player controls
            //player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Video_Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }
private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: simply use a regex expression...

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.split(regex)

For example:

```
String s = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iz6aR-WATYY";
String id = s.split("v=")[1];
```

Comment: @srikanthkanth You have asked how to extract the id from the string, not how to write a loop.

Comment: plz clerify my doubts....i got many video links from server in listView in my app.......how to get id's and pass to next activity

Comment: @srikanthkanth https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: i read above doc....and i used this below code ..String pattern = "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/|youtu.be\\/|\\/v\\/|\\/e\\/|watch\\?v%3D|watch\\?feature=player_embedded&v=|%2Fvideos%2F|embed%\u200C\u200B2F|youtu.be%2F|%2Fv%2F)[^#\\&\\?\\n]*";

        Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url); //url is youtube url for which you want to extract the id.
        if (matcher.find()) {
             return matcher.group();
        }

Comment: madless ..i used your code ..i got error like : There was a problem with the network[400]